# Symfony forms, labels not to be translated

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony-forms, symfony

I have some labels in a form which don't need to be translated (for example, IBAN, PayPal Email, Skype...)

Can i avoid translating them (it would increase the translation files size uselessly), without having the "Missing messages" error?

I'm using a standard Doctrine Entity + FormType class + Twig layout

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your FormType, just set the 'translation_domain' option to false.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html#translation-domain

You can also use this option on the children.